# Append values to dict in class inheritance

Tags: python, abstract-class

I am writing a function that returns a dictionary having one key and several values. I want to make my function as generic as possible allowing me to add as many values as I want to the one existing key.
Below is the code I wrote:

```
import abc


class Properties(object):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def spark_driver_extra_javaOptions(self, job_name, data, *args, **kwargs):
        return
        {
            'spark.driver.extraJavaOptions': '-DAppConfig.appName=%s   -DAppConfig.domain=%s   -D%s.Options.jobName=%s    -DTrm.Metadata.outputBase=%s' % (
                job_name, data, job_name, data)}


    class Childd(Properties):
        def spark_driver_extra_javaOptions(self,job_name, data, prefix, dataset ):
            return {
                'spark.driver.extraJavaOptions': '-DAppConfig.app
```

This is not working properly

I want to find a clever way to make the `Child` class inherited method `spark_driver_extra_javaOptions` append new values to the existing key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to find a clever way to make the `Child` class inherited method `spark_driver_extra_javaOptions` append new values to the existing key.

Without getting too fancy with abstract classes or other python magic, just call the parent method as shown in pseudo code

```
class Properties(object):

    def spark_driver_extra_javaOptions(*args, **kwargs):
        .... # Do stuff
        return {'spark.driver.extraJavaOptions': [...]}

class Child(Properties):
    def spark_driver_extra_javaOptions(*args, **kwargs):
        some_stuff = super().spark_driver_extra_javaOptions(*args, **kwargs) # call parent method
        .... # do more stuff
        more_stuff = [1, 2, 3, ... some more stuff]
        some_stuff['spark.driver.extraJavaOptions'].extend(more_stuff)
        return some_stuff
```